# Prove the inequality $n! > 2^n$ by induction.

Tags: inequality, induction

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Proof the inequality $n! \geq 2^n$ by induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76946/proof-the-inequality-n-geq-2n-by-induction) 
>   [Prove By Induction that $n!&gt;2^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111146/prove-by-induction-that-n2n)

I have to prove the inequality $n! > 2^n$ for all integers $n \geq4$.

I am having trouble with this.

I am assuming that: $n! > 2^n \implies (n+1)! > 2^{n+1}$.

I have proven the base case is true, as $4! > 2^4$.

For the induction step, I get: $(n+1)! = (n+1)n!$

After that, I am not sure what to do.

Thanks.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111146/prove-by-induction-that-n2n

Comment: Hint: for k>2, product(k, k=3..n)>2*2*...*2