# Proof by mathematical induction that $2^n < (n+2)!$ for all $n\ge 0$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, induction, factorial

I have been trying to get this.. For hours.

Prove by M.I. that $2^n < (n+2)!$ for $n\ge0$

Here is what I am doing:

Base case checks out at $n=0$

Make assumption for: $n=k$

Want to prove:   $2^{k+1} < (k+3)!$

I am guessing that since $k\ge 0$, if I just assume $k = 0$ and the inequality holds, then I am done.

But I'm not sure.
If I do that then I get:

PROOF:

$2^k < (k+2)!$ , by assumption

$2^k \times 2 < 2(k+2)!$

$2^{k+1} < (2k+4)!$  but $k\ge 0$, and at Zero

$2< 4!$   done?

Comment: You made a huge error: $2\cdot (k+2)! \neq (2k+4)!$ If, in general, $2\cdot(n!)$ would be equal to $(2n)!)$, then $2\cdot 24$ would be equal to $8!$ which is $40320$!

Comment: Yes, that about did me in. Thx

Comment: See also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76946/prove-the-inequality-n-geq-2n-by-induction) and other questions [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/76946). That inequality is rather similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use $2^n < (n+2)!\Rightarrow 2^{n+1} = 2\cdot 2^n < 2\cdot (n+2)!< (n+3)\cdot (n+2)!=(n+3)!$

Comment: This is what I was trying to do, but I don't understand the logic on the RHS.

Comment: Its simply that $2 < n+3$.

Comment: Now I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is dodgy. You would need to demonstrate that "the property gets more true as $k$ increases, so the worst case is when $k=0$, which we now prove". But if you're starting out, that's not a good line of reasoning to follow, and it can get you into bad habits.

If $2^k < (k+2)!$, how can we transform the inequality to get $2^{k+1}$ on the left-hand side?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a combinatorial argument that $2^n\leq (n+1)!$ for all nonnegative integers $n$.  Consider a sequence $\left(a_0,a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\right)$ where $\left\{a_0,a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\right\}=\{0,1,2,\ldots,n\}$.  There are $(n+1)!$ such sequences.  If $\mathbf{a}:=\left(a_0,a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\right)$ is such a sequence, we say that $\mathbf{a}$ is *extraordinary* if, for every $i=1,2,\ldots,n$, either $$\left\{a_{k-i},a_{k-i+1},\ldots,a_{k-1}\right\}=\left\{0,1,2,\ldots,i-1\right\}\text{ or }\left\{a_{k+1},a_{k+2},\ldots,a_{k+i}\right\}=\left\{0,1,2,\ldots,i-1\right\}\,,$$ given that $a_k=i$.  We shall show that there are $2^n$ extraordinary sequences.  This will prove that $2^n\leq (n+1)!$, which then implies that $2^n<(n+2)!$.

Start with a sequence of length $1$ consisting of $0$ alone.  For each $i=1,2,\ldots,n$, we can assign $i$ either on the *left* (L) or on the *right* (R) of all the previously assigned locations for $0,1,2,\ldots,i-1$.  Hence, extraordinary sequences are in a one-to-one correspondence with a string of length $n$ with letters L and R. For examples, if $n=4$, then LLLL corresponds to $(4,3,2,1,0)$, LRLR corresponds to $(3,1,0,2,4)$, and RLRR corresponds to $(2,0,1,3,4)$.  This proves that the number of extraordinary sequences is $2^n$.