# Prove using mathematical induction that for all $n! \ge 2^{n-1}$

Tags: induction

Prove using mathematical induction that for all $n! \ge 2^{n-1}$

Base case, p(1), 1! >= 1

$p(n+1), n!(n+1) \ge 2^{n-1}(n+1) $

Comment: n+1 is at least equal to 2.....so expression on the right of your last inequality is larger than 2^n

Comment: The statement can also be proven without using mathematical induction: just observe that $n!$ is the product of $n-1$ integers $\ge 2$ (namely, the integers from $2$ to $n$), and so is $\ge 2^{n-1}$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove the inequality $n! \geq 2^n$ by induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76946/prove-the-inequality-n-geq-2n-by-induction)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've basically gotten it. You have

$$ 
(n+1)! = n!(n+1)\\ 
(n+1)! \geq 2^{n-1}(n+1)
$$

Now for all $n\geq1$, $n+1 \geq 2$. Therefore, from above, we've shown that

$$ 
(n+1)! \geq 2^{n-1}(2) = 2^n 
$$

This completes the proof that $\forall n\geq 1,\quad n! \geq 2^{n-1}$.