# Show that $n! ≥ 2^{n-1}$ is true by induction for n being a positive integer

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I start off by doing the base case:

**Base Case:** Let P(n) be $n! \ge 2^{n-1}$. Then $P(1)$ will be:

$$
1! \ge 2^0 
$$
$$
1 \ge 1
$$
So the base case is true.

**Induction:** I assume $P(k)$ is true for some arbitrary positive integer $k$. Now I need to show that $P(k+1)$ is true. So assuming $k! \ge 2^{k-1} $ is true, I need to show that $(k+1)! \ge 2^{(k+1)-1} $ is true.

$$
2^{(k+1)-1} = 2 \cdot  2^{k-1}
$$

$$\le 2 \cdot k! \tag{By inductive hypothesis}$$

**My question** So I have solved this to this point but I don't really know where to take it from here. I would appreciate any help on completing this proof.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove the inequality $n! \geq 2^n$ by induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76946/prove-the-inequality-n-geq-2n-by-induction). This other question asks for a somewhat stronger condition, so it starts at $n = 4$ instead of $n = 1$, but otherwise the induction procedure to follow is basically the same.

Answer (score 2):

From $k! \ge 2^{k-1}$ and $k+1 \ge 1$ we get

$$(k+1)!=k!(k+1) \ge 2^{k-1}(k+1) \ge 2^{k-1} \cdot 2= 2^k.$$