# $(n+1)!>2^{(n+1)}$ for $n$, where $n \geq 4$. (Mathematical Induction)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, matrices

By using Mathematical Induction prove that $(n+1)!>2^{(n+1)}$ for $n$, where $n \geq 4$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove the inequality $n! \geq 2^n$ by induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76946/prove-the-inequality-n-geq-2n-by-induction)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check the base case:
$$((4)+1)!=120>32=2^{(4)+1}$$
Next we want to show that $(k+1)!>2^{k+1}\implies (k+2)!>2^{k+2}$. Since $(k+2)>2$ for all $k \geq 4$ and by hypothesis $(k+1)!>2^{k+1}$, we get
$$(k+2)!=(k+2)(k+1)!>2\cdot 2^{k+1}=2^{k+2}$$

Answer (score 4):

If true for some $k\geq{4}$, that is $(k+1)!>2^{k+1}$, then $(k+2)!=(k+2).(k+1)!>(k+2).2^{k+1}>2.2^{k+1}=2^{k+2}$

Answer (score 3):

$n!=\overbrace{1\times 2\times 3\times 4}^{=24\, >\, 2^4}\times \overbrace{5}^{>2}\times \overbrace{6}^{>2}\cdots\times \overbrace{n}^{>2}>2^4\times 2^{n-4}$